# How to cast a column with data type List[null] to List[i64] in polars

Tags: python-polars

Hey I have the following problem, I'd like to use the polars apply function on columns with the datatype List.
In most cases this works, but in some cases all lists in the column are empty and the column datatype is List[null], in that special case the code is crashing.

Here some example Code:

```
df = pl.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [[]],
    [[]]
], columns=['A']))
df.with_columns(pl.col('A').apply(lambda x:x))
```

results in

```
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Unwrapped panic from Python code
```

I think the problem can be easily solved by cast the datatype to another List datatype, but i have no Idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `polars>=0.13.11` you can:

```py
df = pl.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [[]],
    [[]]
], columns=['A']))


assert df["A"].cast(pl.List(pl.Int64)).dtype.inner == pl.Int64
assert df["A"].cast(pl.List(int)).dtype.inner == pl.Int64
```