# python-polars casting string to numeric

Tags: pandas, python-polars

When applying pandas.to_numeric,Pandas return dtype is float64 or int64 depending on the data supplied.https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

is there an equivelent to do this in polars?

I have seen this [How to cast a column with data type List[null] to List[i64] in polars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441375/how-to-cast-a-column-with-data-type-listnull-to-listi64-in-polars) however dont want to  individually cast each column. got couple of string columns i want to turn numeric. this could be int or float values

```
#code to show casting in pandas.to_numeric
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["1","2"], "col2":["3.5", "4.6"]})
print("DataFrame:")
print(df)
df[["col1","col2"]]=df[["col1","col2"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Pandas, Polars is quite picky about datatypes and tends to be rather unaccommodating when it comes to automatic casting.  (Among the reasons is performance.)

You can create a feature request for a `to_numeric` method (but I'm not sure how enthusiastic the response will be.)

That said, here's some easy ways to accomplish this.

##### Create a method

Perhaps the simplest way is to write a method that attempts the cast to integer and then catches the exception.  For convenience, you can even attach this method to the `Series` class itself.

```py
def to_numeric(s: pl.Series) -> pl.Series:
    try:
        result = s.cast(pl.Int64)
    except pl.exceptions.ComputeError:
        result = s.cast(pl.Float64)
    return result


pl.Series.to_numeric = to_numeric
```

Then to use it:

```py
(
    pl.select(
        s.to_numeric()
        for s in df
    )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 3.5  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 4.6  │
└──────┴──────┘
```

##### Use the automatic casting of csv parsing

Another method is to write your columns to a csv file (in a string buffer), and then have [`read_csv`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html) try to infer the types automatically.  You may have to tweak the `infer_schema_length` parameter in some situations.

```py
from io import StringIO
pl.read_csv(StringIO(df.write_csv()))
```

```
>>> pl.read_csv(StringIO(df.write_csv()))
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 3.5  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 4.6  │
└──────┴──────┘
```